# How to extract ajax response data from the success callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find any satisfying answers in the previous posts.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: function(data) {
            // Data received here
        }
    });
});
```

[or]

```
someFunction() {
    return $.ajax({
        // Call and receive data
    });
}

var myVariable;

someFunction().done(function(data) {
    myVariable = data;
    // Do stuff with myVariable
});
```

The above code works just fine. However, this ajax request is made on page load and I want to process this data later on. I know I can include the processing logic inside the callback but I don't want to do that. Assigning the response to a global variable is not working either because of the asynchronous nature of the call.

In both the above ways, the 'data' is confined either to the success callback or the done callback and I want to access it outside of these if possible. This was previously possible with jQuery 'async:false' flag but this is deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When do you want to process the data? Upon some event like button press?

Comment: Something like that... My issue is, the ajax request is the first thing that happens and as a result I have to add remaining of the application logic[that depends on data] inside this callback and it's all becoming a mess very quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "outsource" the callback to a normal function, so you can put it somewhere, you like it:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: yourOwnCallback
    });
});
```

somehwere else you can define your callback

```
function yourOwnCallback(data) {
  // Data received and processed here
}
```

this is even possible with object methods as well

Comment: Please note the deprecation notice in the ajax documentation: `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` I think using `.done` is preferred to `success:`. Unlike `success` the `.done` method is chained to the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

This solution might not be idea but I hope it helps.

- Set the variable upon callback.
- Wherever you need to process the data, check if variable is set and if not wait somehow.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myVar = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: function(data) {
            myVar=data;
        }
    });

    someFunction(){ //this is invoked when you need processing
        while(myVar==false){}
        ... do some other stuff ..
    }
});
```

Or

```
someFunction(){
    if(myVar==false){
        setTimeout(someFunction(),100); //try again in 100ms
        return;
    }
.. do some other stuff ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Waiting somehow is the hard part though..:)

Comment: @Sparda: Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't really have a blocking sleep function, so you have to enclose the code inside a function and keep playing with setTimeout :/ You could also play around with [jQuery().when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), but I don't think that will be any easier.

Comment: @Sparda: Hope it helps. Shame that JavaScript doesn't let us do those kind of things easily.